# Migrating code away from Github to Google code back to Github

Tags: github, fork

The google dat.gui is a great little interface. http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage

I really want to use this on a new project, but it doesn't work properly on touch screen devices.

However, since they migrated it from Github to code.google.com, things seems to have stalled and issues are going unfixed.

Being brutally honest, I think the project would have more community contribution if it were back on Github. Could I fork it and create my own version, called something like dat.gui MkII, and encourage people to contribute to my version on github? The problem however, is I don't want things to get diluted and create confusion. Would it be better just to completely rebrand it away from dat.gui, and say it was originally forked from there?

Answer (score 1):

Apply a
[Cost–benefit analysis](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost%E2%80%93benefit_analysis)
to forking the project.

Cost

```
forking could dilute the project and create confusion
```

Benefit

```
could renew interest in the project and result in more issues being fixed
```

In my opinion it is worth it, you could alleviate some confusion by having a detailed README on your homepage decribing the situation and/or linking here.